# Why is my elisp function not accepting a second parameter?

Tags: org-mode, elisp, org-table

@Juancho gave a great answer to a [question I asked a few days ago](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13817/can-columns-of-an-org-table-be-grouped-to-conveniently-work-with-data/13843#13843). My question is about how to modify his elisp code.

I have an `org` table

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results none
  (defun jj/factor (code)
      (cond ((eq (string-to-char code) ?P) .05)
            (t 0)))

  (defun jj/factorlist (codelist)
    (mapcar 'jj/factor codelist))

  (defun jj/dotproduct (a b)
    (apply '+ (mapcar* '* (jj/factorlist a) (mapcar 'string-to-number b))))
#+end_src


|        |        |   P1 |   P2 |   Q1 |   Q2 |   E1 |   E2 |    F |
|--------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------|
|        | Totals |   20 |   40 |   50 |   45 |  100 |  100 |  200 |
|--------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------|
| John   |   0.10 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
| Paul   |   1.00 |   10 |   10 |   10 |   10 |   10 |   10 |   10 |
| George |  10.00 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |
| Ringo  | 100.00 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
#+TBLFM: @3$2..@>$2='(jj/dotproduct (list @1$3..@1$>) (list $3..$>));%.2f
```

The function `jj/dotproduct` takes the entries in the columns marked `P`, multiplies them by `.05`, and adds them up in the column marked `Totals`.

Now, I'd like to modify `jj/dotproduct` so it takes another input `x` where `x` any letter. This would allow me to sum the columns marked `Q`, `E`, and `F` separately. I've tried modifying it as follows

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results none
  (defun jj/factor (code x)
      (cond ((eq (string-to-char code) (string-to-char x)) .05)
            (t 0)))

  (defun jj/factorlist (codelist x)
    (mapcar 'jj/factor codelist x))

  (defun jj/dotproduct (x a b)
    (apply '+ (mapcar* '* (jj/factorlist a x) (mapcar 'string-to-number b))))
#+end_src


|        |        |   P1 |   P2 |   Q1 |   Q2 |   E1 |   E2 |    F |
|--------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------|
|        | Totals |   20 |   40 |   50 |   45 |  100 |  100 |  200 |
|--------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------|
| John   |   0.00 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
| Paul   |   0.00 |   10 |   10 |   10 |   10 |   10 |   10 |   10 |
| George |   0.00 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |
| Ringo  |   0.00 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
#+TBLFM: @3$2..@>$2='(jj/dotproduct "P" (list @1$3..@1$>) (list $3..$>));%.2f
```

This, however, gives the wrong output. Any ideas what I've done wrong and how I can fix my code?

Comment: See `C-h f mapcar`. It takes two arguments -- a function and a sequence. You're now trying to pass it an additional argument, which it can't use.

Comment: What @phils said. You have a problem  here: `(mapcar 'jj/factor codelist x)`.

Comment: FYO, `cl-mapcar` takes arbitrary many lists (that's also the behavior of Common Lisp `mapcar`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, you're trying to pass more arguments to `mapcar` than it takes. You must only pass it a function and a sequence.

An elegant way to solve your problem is to use `apply-partially` to obtain the function you need. Note that we need `x` to be the first argument to `jj/factor`.

```el
(defun jj/factor (x code)
  (cond ((eq (string-to-char code) (string-to-char x)) .05)
        (t 0)))

(defun jj/factorlist (codelist x)
  (mapcar (apply-partially 'jj/factor x) codelist))

(defun jj/dotproduct (x a b)
  (apply '+ (mapcar* '* (jj/factorlist a x) (mapcar 'string-to-number b))))
```

Comment: Ahh cool. So apply-partially is the mathematical analogue of given a y defining f(x)=F(x,y). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Or without `apply-partially`: ``(mapcar `(lambda (cd) (jj/factor ,x cd)) codelist)``.

Comment: I meant to add that `apply-partially` is usable only if the arguments you want to apply the function to partially are the first parameters it accepts, and in the same order. Using `lambda` (or a `defun`) lets you apply the function partially to any subset of arguments, supplied in any order.